# Stack area series on top of line series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need a way to stack an area series on top of a line series that goes through the charts. Is there a way to always stack a specific series?

[image]

```
I have a codpen where i build the example:
```

https://codepen.io/kraften/pen/PvVOxb

Answer (score 0):

You can stack two `area` series, one with `fillColor: 'transparent'`:

```
chart: {
    type: 'area'
},
series: [{
    data: [...],
    type: 'line'
}, {
    data: [...],
    stacking: 'normal',
    stack: 'one'
}, {
    data: [...],
    fillColor: 'transparent',
    stacking: 'normal',
    stack: 'one'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tnwz5psa/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.fillColor

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.stack

Comment: Okey, that might not be a bad idea! Thanks I will try it out!